# Creating boot.scr for u-boot

Tags: linux, boot, u-boot, yocto

I generate image for a Freescale i.mx6 sabresd using Yocto.
When booting, to activate the hdmi I have to modify u-boot by editing the bootargs. I use the following command :

```
setenv mmcargs 'setenv bootargs console=ttymxc0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk2p2 rootwait rw video=mxcfb0:dev=hdmi, 1920x1080M@60, if=RGB24'
```

I can use `saveenv` to not enter it at every boot, but I'd like to automatize it to make the deployment easier. So I have made a boot.scr. Here is the boot.txt :

```
setenv mmcargs 'setenv bootargs console=ttymxc0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk2p2 rootwait rw video=mxcfb0:dev=hdmi, 1920x1080M@60, if=RGB24'
boot
```

And I create the boot.scr using `mkimage -A arm -T script -O linux -d boot.txt boot.scr`. But, when booting, it makes a loop (`boot` make uboot reload the configuration, where it reads `boot` so it begin again). Without `boot`... no boot. I've tried a lot of possibilities : `boot 0x120000000`, `bootm`, `bootz`, with a lot of options, nothing works.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, your boot fails because you never load a kernel from which you could boot from.

In most cases, if *bootcmd* loads a boot.scr, then it is up to your boot.scr script to load the kernel (and also a device tree assuming you are using a recent iMX6 kernel).  Then your script may boot with this kernel or allow *bootcmd* to carry on with its boot sequence using the loaded kernel.  The load commands would look something like:

```
loadfdt=fatload mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${fdt_addr} ${fdt_file}
loaduimage=fatload mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${loadaddr} ${uimage}
```

And the boot command should look something like:

```
run loaduimage; run loadfdt; bootm ${loadaddr} - ${fdt_addr}
```

You may already have an *mmcboot* command defined which already takes care of these.

I would remove the "boot" line from your script and instead load the kernel and device tree and then run bootm (or mmcboot) - basically try adding the above three lines to your script after setting mmcarg - you'll need to ensure all referenced variables are properly set (ie. mmcdev, mmpart, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer from shibley, I've found a simpler way :

```
run loadimage
run mmcboot
```

He was right, `mmcboot` takes care of the booting of the kernel. But I have to run `loadimage` (not `loaduimage)` before.